# Compile boost under win xp with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, mingw, bjam

I'm trying to compile the boost 1.49 using bjam.exe. I found the commandline:

```
bjam.exe toolset=gcc variant=release threading=multi link=static boost_thread
```

but it throws some errors:

```
warning: mismatched versions of Boost.Build engine and core
warning: Boost.Build engine (bjam.exe) is 03.1.18
warning: Boost.Build core (at ./tools/build/vs) is 2011.04-svn
./tools/build/vs/tools/gcc.jam:129: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization
error: no command provided, default command 'g++' not found
error: initialized from ./tools/build/v2/user-config.jam:42
./tools/build/v2/build/toolset.jam:38 in toolset.using from module toolset
./tools/build/v2/build/project.jam:888 in using from module project-rules
./tools/build/v2/user-config.jam:42 in modules.load from module user-config
./tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:257 in load-config from module build-system
./tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:399 in load-configuration-files from module build-system
./tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:555: in load from module build-system
./tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
./tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
./boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

How can I make bjam know where gcc is (I installed it with MinGW and Codeblocks)? How can I have the right version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is not really the best place to ask, as it is Windows related question.
The best way (for it will work for other apps) is just to add your MinGW to PATH variable.

Go here for reference on how to do that: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: What does w3s have in contact with this topic ? Why is stackoverflow not the right point to ask windows-related questions ? But I'll try your hint adding MinGW to PATH.

Comment: @friedzis It just compiles. I hope I can link it afterwards.

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens Sorry, copied a link from wrong tab (had it open for other question) (:

Comment: No problem, it compiled well. But boost::thread::join is still not referenced. The rest works.